# Missing package product <Package Dependencies name>

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dependencies, swift-package-manager

I am trying to migrate my existing project to **Swift Package Manager** from **Cocoapods**.

I have added all my dependencies. All my dependencies are in Remote

***Ex.:** Firebase, Realm, etc.,*

When I try to build I am getting following error.

[image: You can find the error here]

I tried to resolve in all the following ways but couldn't workout:

1. Reset packages
2. Update to latest package versions
3. Resolve package versions
4. Delete derived data
5. Clean build folder
6. Quit/Relaunch the Xcode
7. Adding the packages from Project Navigator & File -> Add Packages

Has anyone experienced this issue? Any idea what this could be?
**FYI**: I am using Xcode 13.2.1

Comment: From the project navigator select your project and go to the "Package Dependencies" tab. Do you see all of your packages there? Also, are you sure you cleaned out all of your cocoapods? Are you working with an .xcodeproj or a .xcworkspace?

Comment: @RobC Yes. I have all the packages under "Package Dependencies" tab. I did pod deIntegrate. Am working with .xcodeproj

Comment: what is the output from running this command in terminal?  
  
`sw_vers ; echo ; xcodebuild -version ; echo ; swift --version`

Answer (score 3):

Open Finder and go to your Project directory.

1. Show package contents of .xcodeproj
2. Inside this new folder, Show package contents of .xcworkspace
3. Open xcshareddata
4. Open swiftpm
5. Delete package.resolved
6. Now do all the steps you tried before

Comment: Did upto 3rd step. I can't see "swiftpm" inside "xcshareddata". I just have "xcschemes" inside "xcshareddata".